# A Windows Based PHP Compiler?

Tags: php, windows, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP compiler for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189100/php-compiler-for-windows)

I am looking for a PHP compiler like [phc](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.bcompiler.php) that I can use on my windows machine hopefully with a GUI (!). It needs to work with PHP version 5.3.x. A freely available compiler is what I am looking for.

I have had no luck in finding something that works with php 5.3 and that is actively being developed.

A quick question about PHP compilers. If I compiled my php code would I need to run that compiled script in the same PHP version? Or can I use version 5.2.x, 5.1.x, if compiled with 5.3.x?

Secondly, how does embedded PHP in HTMl work when it is compiled?

Apologies for these nooby questions but today is the first day of attempting to compile PHP code, but I can't find a suitable compiler yet!

Comment: [Previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189100/php-compiler-for-windows) to this same question

Comment: @JYelton - PHP can be compiled, but it generally ain't pretty

Comment: I would assume that PHP could, theoretically, be compiled. However, it is usually, as JYelton implied, interpreted, and thus doesn't need a compiler. I could see using compiled PHP to write command line utilities or some such, but stick with interpreted PHP for web applications.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if its an interpreted language or not, it is compiled by the Zend Engine into operation code when the script is requested.

Comment: it can't be called compilation in traditional sense. This technique is called Just In Time compilation. It means that yes, it is compiled, but you can't create standalone executables using it.

Comment: My [answer from 2009](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401/hidden-features-of-php/1066936#1066936), still valid.