# compiling PHP 5 to EXE?

Tags: php

i have been using the awesome bambalam: http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/ compiler to make exe from php source.

But it's getting old, and it doesn't support php5.

Is there another project that will do the trick?

Thanks

ADD1:
i need only for windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP compiler for windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189100/php-compiler-for-windows)

Comment: @Matt Ball: When I answered it didn't say for windows, it really should have, makes a big difference to answers.

Comment: @Orbling: your point? The question has changed; change your answer accordingly. This has nothing to do with me. I simply identified a dup.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Was just commenting...

Comment: I thought it was clear since i said exe anyway.. yes i need only for windows

Comment: try this: http://www.exeoutput.com/

Comment: PHP-Nightrain is an very good compiler - and is cross-platform (Windows, OSX, Linux). While it had a bad reputation because of the dependency on Java, it has now switched to Python as a wrapper, and is a very good choice for developing cross-platform software based on PHP. -- github.com/naetech/nightrain

Answer (score 3):

> **Please note, this was answered before the OP added the vitally important "I need only for windows" addition to the question.**

---

Well the way Facebook handle this is by compiling to an intermediary language, C++, via a piece of software called [HipHop for PHP](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/).

There's also [PHC](http://www.phpcompiler.org/), and a few others.  [Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/) caches the bytecode which helps a lot.

Comment: phc and hiphop don't support windows.

Comment: @Paul Biggar: Please note the note, added a fortnight ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can try exe output, get it here, www.exeoutput.com. It has amazing features supports html, flash, javascript, php, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to one of these tools:

- [PHPFlexer](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/PHPFlexer.shtml), if you only have a single php file (like a quick commandline tool)
- [RapidEXE](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/RapidEXE.shtml), if it's several files/folders; here you can even choose a PHP version
- [PHC-Win](https://jaredallard.me/phc-win/), it's the ancestor of PHPFlexer and works pretty well
- [ExeOutput](https://www.exeoutput.com/), a big monster but it gives you a webserver environment and a nice GUI
- [ZZEE](https://www.zzee.com/), despite its silly name it's pretty good but features some oldish PHP

The first 3 is command-line, the last 2 are able to develop a window-based application; but they're slow, sometimes a bit tricky to configure and they also make a big fat exe file that loads relatively slow (especially ExeOutput). Command line ones are pretty compact and easy to use, with an output exe around 2MB.