# PHP: What do you recommend me to compile my standalone (not web-based) PHP application?

Tags: php, compilation

I have developed an application in **PHP** that acts as a service; I mean it does not need to be run under a Web Server. I want a way to **protect my libraries** so I can release a commercial version along the open source one.
What do you recommend to **compile** the code or any other method to achieve this purpose, please?

Comment: Depending on what you really mean by *compiling*, this is a possible duplicate of [Can you "compile" PHP code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code) or [Code obfuscator for php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php)

Comment: thanks, but you'r not right. i know about compilers. i have asked about my specific need, compiling a CLI php application. those you mentioned, one asks for a general compiler and one asks for his specific need. so they're not related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

We have used [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) on one of our projects due to such requirement. Aside from minor code modifications (removing autoloader and similar), it worked out well. The only downside is the licence price, but since it was paid by client as it was their request, we had no problems with that.

**Update:** Forgot earlier, project was mostly web based app, but there was around 8-10% of it CLI, and there was no problem with it either.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
http://www.phpcompiler.org/

Comment: thanks, i've seen that. have you used it or any experience about it?

Comment: No I don't, but you are asking for a protection this is why I listed this compiler "# Obfuscate PHP code (--obfuscate flag - experimental).", but I really have no idea how good this compiler is. Also check this post, it may help in someway:http://blog.paulbiggar.com/archive/a-rant-about-php-compilers-in-general-and-hiphop-in-particular/

Comment: thanks about the article. it changed my mind about phc (http://phpcompiler.org) and hiphop completely!!