# PHP : Can I compile/build my site like .NET?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, and working on a class based web site. So my question is simple. Can I compile the site like I can in .NET?

This would be helpful to me because I changed my IsAAction interface to accept an error callback function as a parameter of the Execute function, and I would like all of my implementations to break so I can easily see where to change them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP source is compiled to bytecode by the Zend engine when it's parsed. Alternatively, you can "compile" PHP into C++ using [HipHop for PHP](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) which is what Facebook does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can be compiled, as in you can compile it to machine code and prevent a parsing everytime you access a file. That the way accelerator like APC work. But you can't compile it like a .NET DLL with every error checked in advance. It would go against its dynamic nature. Late binding mean it will always check for error at runtime

For your particuliar problem, I would suggest adding Unit Tests to your project. They are *very* good to have anyway, and they will help you catch error in your interface implementation. I personally couldn't live without them. You may want to check PHPUnit or SimpleTests.

EDIT To understand why PHP can't check your error, just check this snippet of code.

```
if ($_GET['impl'] == 'interface1') {
    interface MyInterface {
        function foo($var);
    }
} else {
    interface MyInterface {
        function bar($var, $var2);
    }
}

class Implementation implements MyInterface { //Will crash or not depending on the URL!
    function foo($var) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. See:

[Can you "compile" PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code)

And:

http://www.phpcompiler.org/

And:

http://www.scriptol.com/apollo.php

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki -  although I'm sure there are [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code) on here that you'd find useful.

Answer (score 1):

There's a opened topic on stackoverflow that is related.

[Can you “compile” PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code)

Some parties such as **Facebook** rewrote **PHP runtime**, or part of it so they make it possible to run compiled php code or other source codes, pretty much whatever you like.

[HipHop for PHP](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/)

Its not an easy task. But you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. PHP is a script language.