# Why can't I compile PHP code?

Tags: php, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you “compile” PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code)

After I write an application in PHP, why can't I compile it into machine language? I know that it's possible to make a byte-code version of the file, which (as I understand it) is basically a file that has already been parsed into tokens.

But that's not what I want. Clearly it can't work in a general sense, since compiled code will be platform-specific, but let's say I have chosen a given platform. Why can't I create a binary file that would be the same code that PHP would run when given my .php file?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to write a machine-code targeting compiler first? Let us know when you have one! :-)

Comment: Doesn't PHP just run in a VM?  Might be wrong, but that's what I though was the case.  If so, you're not running on the platform but on the VM.

Comment: Why don't you just Google for "PHP compiler"?

Comment: Bytecode has nothing to do with tokens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, facebook released a project which is currently being updated for php 5.3 (supports everything lower iirc) called HipHop, you can find it here: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php

Answer (score 1):

There are a few compilers out there like facebook's, mentioned by @Howard, or http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php?pageID=compiler. I've never tried them though.