# What is the current status of compilers for PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, linux, compiler-construction, obfuscation

I tried searching for simple compilers to obfuscate PHP source code by converting them to opcode. But it seems many are no longer in active development, e.g. PHC, bcompiler. HipHop developed by Facebook seems complicated and works only on a 64-bit OS. Then, there are others that requires .NET framework. Is there a compiler that works with PHP 5.4 installed on Linux?

Other forms of obfuscation that involves PHP function such as `eval` will make debugging complicated, so, I am not looking at those at the moment.

Some related questions I have looked into:
[Can you "compile" PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1408417) 
[How to compile php source code in PHP 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13130865)

Comment: Look for IonCube or Zend Guard.

Comment: @N.B., yes, I am aware of these propriety products. Wonder if there are open source ones similar to bcompiler.

Comment: The functionality of obfuscating compilers like IonCube and ZendGuard depends on their being obscure (e.g, closed source). An open-source equivalent would be unreasonably easy to bypass.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Guard is closed source, but free. The following comparison table might be helpful for you:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators#Feature_Table