# Make a Web Crawler in php

Tags: php, web-crawler

I want to build a web crawler with PHP, but I  am still confused about this. I have not found a tutorial that can working.

Can anyone help me how to build a crawler with PHP?

Comment: Are you just looking for a tutorial on how to program in PHP?  There are plenty of those out there.  If you're past that step, where are you stuck?  What have you tried and in what way is that attempt not working?

Answer (score 2):

Building a web crawler involves opening pages, parsing them for the data you'd like and for links to other pages, and following those links. For reading pages, you'll want to look at the [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function. For parsing pages (including identifying links), you'll want to look at [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Answer (score 2):

Also you can start from this php open source
[sphider php search engine](http://www.sphider.eu/)

Answer (score 2):

At first, you should ask yourself how would this crawler work?

The PHP typical use is preparing dynamically a web page (eg. in HTML code). The PHP generates the HTML code and the server sends prepared document to the user. This is done when user requests it. Normally your web crawler will be then run when users open your page, and in my opinion it makes no sense because it takes too much time to crawl and the user would have to wait.

There is another possibility, that you want to crawl some parts of your page. In this case you can store contents in some database and use PHP to query the db. But this is not a crawler, because db engine has already indexed all content and can find everything you need.

The third way is a possibility to run your PHP program from command line (both Windows and Linux) so the crawler would be run by you, not the user. For more information how to achieve this, please refer to [quinxorin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17025226/2088851). This answer is short as the subject is quite wide.

It is also possible to [compile PHP programs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1408417/2088851).

In my opinion, if you're the beginner, it's better not to start with such large tasks. First, try to learn how to make with PHP simple webpage, and then you will now how crawlers are made.