# Can we make EXE equivalent for PHP code so that the code can be protected?

Tags: php

Not sure if this has been discussed before. 
I was looking for a solution that can protect the PHP code. 
So even if I put the code on my client's server if they decide to put another developer on it or try to resell my code they should not be able to do so.

Is that even remotely possible?
The .exe versions of desktop application thingy is something I am looking for, but for PHP.

Comment: If you're not sure if it's been discussed before, then you should do a search to check.  As you can see it didn't take much effort to turn up 2 similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are options to "compile" code like [phpcompiler](http://www.phpcompiler.org/) also read another thread about this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408499/2375204)