# How is node.js asynchronous http.request call implemented?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

How is it implemented asynchronously? does it internally create threads which polls for response.
If so, does it provide any performance benefit over implementing it in multithreaded (with user managed threads) synchronous way.

Comment: Why don't you try to look at the source of node.js ? Since it's an open source project, you have this privilege.

Comment: I am sure you must have had a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17608144/1520671)

Comment: @Christos: Source code of node.js is huge. Finding implementation of certain API can be difficult for a beginner like me. Though reading the source code will be a great learning experience in itself, I'm more interested in performance of Asynchronous method v/s Synchronous one as a end user.
I hope my question now seems justified.