# How does nodejs works asynchronously?

Tags: node.js

I get the response from **/route1**  until **/route2** logs "ROUTE2".

But I studied that nodejs puts functions like setTimeout() in external threads and the main thread continues to work. Shouldn't the for loop executed in an external thread?

```
app.get("/route1",(req,res)=>
{
    res.send("Route1");
});

app.get("/route2",(req,res)=>
{
    setTimeout(()=>
    {
        console.log("ROUTE2");
        for(let i=0;i<1000000000000000;i++);
        res.send("Route2");
    },10000);
})
```

Comment: Please go thorugh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607280/why-is-node-js-asynchronous

Comment: Where did you read `setTimeout` is executed in other thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js uses an `Event Loop` to handle **Asynchronous operations**. And by Asynchronous operations I mean all *I/O operations like interaction with the system's disk or network, Callback functions and Timers(setTimeout, setInterval)*. If you put **Synchronous operations** like a long running `for loop` inside a Timer or a Callback, it will block the event loop from executing the next Callback or I/O Operation.

In above case both `/route1` and `/route2` are Callbacks, so when you hit them, each callback is put into the Event Loop.

Below scenarios will give clear understanding on Asynchronous nature of Node.js:

1. Hit `/route2` first and **within 10 Seconds**(Since setTimeout is for 10000 ms) hit `/route1`

In this case you will see the output *Route 1* because setTimeout for 10 secs still isn't complete. So everything is asynchronous.

2. Hit `/route2` first and **after 10 Seconds**(Since setTimeout is for 10000 ms) hit `/route1`

In this case you will have to wait *till the for loop execution is complete*

```
for(let i=0;i<1000000000000000;i++);
```

because a `for loop` is still a **Synchronous operation** so `/route1` will have to wait till `/route2` ends

> Refer below Node.js Guides for more details:

[Blocking vs Non-Blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/)

[The Node.js Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)