# Has anyone been successful getting Joomla running under IIS/Phalanger?

Tags: iis, joomla, phalanger

Has anyone been successful getting Joomla running under **IIS/Phalanger**?

I have gone through the Phalanger 3.0 installation, followed the instructions on making Joomla a app that runs using the Phalanger compiler, but for some reason I get an error before the app even starts up:

```
Error: Class 'JLogEntry' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\nfspv3\libraries\joomla\log\log.php on line 169, column 4.
```

I was running Joomla 2.5 on `IIS/MySQL` prior to installing Phalanger 3.0 so I am wondering if it's an issue with the Phalanger compiler not interpreting the PHP right?  Would be good to know if anyone has Joomla working with Phalanger ok.

Comment: Are you able to put a breakpoint in the PHP code? This would need some debugging ...

Comment: Under Apache/PHP I can with XDebug, but I don't know if Phalanger supports debugging.   The code worked fine under IIS/ISAPI interface, but it would be helpful to step through the code for sure.

Comment: I've just noticed, you are using Phalanger 3.0 ... try 4.0 latest preview at http://pub.devsense.com/phptools/Phalanger.4.0.Tools.1.15.7667.msi ..

Comment: @JakubMíšek I tried with 3.0 AND 4.0 and the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the class `JLogEntry` hasn't been defined, yet it has been referenced by something the expects it to be defined.  This means a dependency wasn't satisfied.  Your `log.php` is dependant on a file that defines the `JLogEntry` class.  The `JLogEntry` class is defined in `entry.php` according to this:

http://www.reference.joomlademo.de/nav.html?_classes/index.html

and this:

http://www.reference.joomlademo.de/nav.html?_classes/index.html

So for whatever reason you're not satisfying that dependency.  If I was on your system I'd poke around for that file, check if it exists, is corrupt, correctly versioned, or otherwise prevented from being executed.

If you still suspect something is hinky with your Phalanger compiler then test it.  Write a simple ["hello world"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849763/hello-world-in-phalanger-php-compiler) and prove whether it works or not. Infact do it in the same file (after backing up the file) to prove whether it's executing.  The compiler is working at some level or else it wouldn't be showing you error messages.

Edit:

According to @highcore the Phalanger 3.0 compiler fails to implement regular expressions in the way Joomla expects. Joomla relies on this to resolve the filenames it will include.  Thus, `entry.php` is never included leaving `JLogEntry` undefined.  The suggested work around is to avoid reg ex and split the file names.

Comment: @highcore Rather than this providing you a canned fix for your problem this answer is an attempt to point you in the direction of discovering one.  It certainly seems you are not alone: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=680673

Comment: @CandledOrange I've been in contact with Phalanger support, and it seems this is an error in the compiler, which incorrectly parses a certain regular expression used by joomla to resolve filenames, which causes the incorrect file name to try to be included and therefore the classes are missing. I've been too busy to post an answer myself, but I already found a workaround (by manually splitting the words without using regex)

Comment: @highcore Ah, well it seems I've arrived to late to help.  Good luck.

Comment: Yep. There is issue with Phalanger perl regexp implementation (https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger/blob/master/Source/ClassLibrary/RegExpPerl.cs) and class names are translated to file paths incorrectly.