# PHP Manual Encoding

Tags: php, encode

My question is how to encode php codes but I am not looking for a site to do it ( or a program ) .
I am asking how to encode manually ? I mean how to change out codes into an unknown string so others may not understand what our codes are .

Comment: That is commonly called "encryption". Knowing that, use Google.

Comment: Or maybe you are talking about 'obfuscating', what means make the source code unreadable for humans.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a compiler to compile your PHP code into byte code and add some obfuscation so that others cannot gain access to your code. Here are a few:

1. http://www.phpcompiler.org/
2. http://www.php-compiler.net/
3. https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/ - This one is launched by Facebook
4. http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/
5. http://sourceforge.net/projects/binaryphp/
6. http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php?pageID=compiler

Some (if not all) of these compilers have features to obfuscate your code.

More at [Can you "compile" PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code)