# Adding extensions into roadsend-php

Tags: php, compilation, installation

I have a program in PHP using ncurses (installed with pecl), I wanted too compile it into as binary with roadsend-php, but it'd seem ncurses isn't included into it. Is there a way I could add it?

-- **EDIT** --

If it can't be done with roadsend-php, *is* there another compiler I could use that could achieve this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t know if you can do it with Roadsend PHP, but you should know that [Roadsend PHP is discontinued as of 2010](http://roadsend-php.blogspot.cz/2010/08/current-status.html).

Try out another PHP compiler, e.g. [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/) that compiles PHP to .NET CIL and originated at my university. You can find a list in [the accepted answer to Can you compile PHP code? question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408499/2157640) here on SO. I updated it a moment ago.