# Apache Server - do something before php processing

Tags: php, apache, parsing, module

**Intro**

I am trying to protect PHP source code from being "easily" read by others, as part of a client requirement.

The thing is, I have tried lot of alternatives:

1) bcompiler: with the intention to transform php source to bytecodes, but no success.

2)phc: imposible to make/install.

3)BLENC extension: I have problems integrating it with a Yii Framework App.

**The Idea**

I was thinking that "maybe" I can "stay" between ApacheServer and PHP, in order to do something like this ...

1) HTTP request comes to APACHE SERVER

2) APACHE checks its a php file

3) According to the URL I know those php files are zipped/encoded, so before APACHE parses them, I unzip/decode the files

4) APACHE parses and process PHP.

5) zip/encode the files again (for protection).

6) Return a result.

**Performance is not a concern**

**Is this posible?**

**Any suggestion?**

**EDITED:**

1) FYI: The server where my php web app runs, is not a hosting, its my client server, so people has access to it.

2) FYI: Right now I found a temporary solution, called, SourceGuardian (http://www.sourceguardian.com/)

After trying BCompiler (imposible to use with PHP 5.4+) , PHC (imposible to compile),Monas (OLD deprecated), BLENC (not thinked for web applications with tons of files different than php files),  etc. etc. etc., trying to "HIDE" my PHP Source code, SourceGuardian was the only think that worked for me, its commercial, but costs 199 dollards, its very affordable. I recommend everybody to try it.

--> (I will keep looking foward to Apache Modules) <--

Comment: What you want is [pre-compiled PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Apache Modules` to make any change while processing your request on server. You can tap the request in almost any level.

You can find about apache modules here :
https://modules.apache.org/

But my concern is , what ever you do output from server should be `HTML + java scripts + etc` readable by your browser.

Comment: PHP comments are not visible if you do view-source in browser. But the output is viewable as in answer above

Comment: Right now I am reading about Apache Modules and Filters.

I will clarify more my question in order tu understand better what I want

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you don't mean Javascript instead?
PHP-Code can only read who has file-access to the server. There is no way to read it with a web browser.

If you really want to "protect" your php source use a simple minifier. It makes the code unreadable.

Comment: I will clarify in my original question

Comment: But when the client has access to the server - he can just read the file without use apache at all. So as i said, use a minifier.

Comment: supose I have my php files encoded somehow, and they can only be decoded by something ... then the php files would be unreadable by anyone.

The Apache modules are a good idea, because I can have my encoding/decoding algo inside the module, and I can filter what to decode depending on the request.

Comment: Now i get it :) Yes than you have to write an Apache Module - the only question is: is it the expense worth? I would prefer the minifier: less work for you, but still unprofitable effort for the "thief".

Comment: Its necesary. because sometimes you sell a software product to someone, than you do another contract in order to maintain and give support, some modifications, etc. Thats why I wanted to be CLSED SOURCE, in order to protect the maintanance contract. Thats my case.