# How can i combine 2 programs written in different programming languages together

Tags: django, network-programming, erlang, programming-languages

I have a django web app and my friends have made a messaging app in erlang and I want to combine both of them so that the users and their friends can communicate.

We are trying build something like facebook, their main web languages is php but they use erlang for messanger

Comment: You create libraries and import them to the foreign code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code

Comment: How do i do that with python

Comment: google *python library compile* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650243/convert-python-program-to-c-c-code

Comment: Read up on [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). These days IPC usually means performing HTTP requests, and since you appear to show low familiarity with these matters, HTTP supposedly is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Rest API, you can communicate Java with Erlang, With C++, With Python, Haskel, just about anything that you can turn into a small server and create a Rest API you can use to communicate multiple services without having ever to care for which language they were created with.

Comment: I was kinda googling and found out about thrift, what do you think about thrift and should i use it over REST